# How is rotational movement of an object using a gyroscope reliably scripted in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gyroscope

I'm trying to add control of my Android game's character using the phone's angle (with upright portrait mode being the 0 point and turning it left or right controlling the angle), but I don't find a method which does it well.

I tried debugging using Gyroscope.RotationRateUnbiased.z (converted to degrees and multiplied by Time.fixedDeltaTime) and adding that into a float during each update, but it seems to easily result in lost calibration as if the phone is rotated during a non-upright position it would still add onto the saved float and thus when you readjust your holding your rotation would be at an offset versus the original calibration. It also doesn't track completely accurately so if you rotate your phone very quickly it might as well result in development of offset.

The other option I tried is using Gyroscope.attitude, but I don't see any of the axes reacting directly to the rotational axis I'm after. I monitored each of the axes converted to euler angles and nothing reacts to it like one would expect. It seems to me like it uses the compass instead as it keeps changing when I rotate in relation to the north pole rather than specifically according to how parallel is the phone to the ground.

So how do I get a measurement of how close is the phone to being parallel to the ground sideways?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've had issues trying to do something similar, I would say that `Gyroscope.attitude` is your best bet. I think a 0 rotation is the phone held upright pointing towards north... perhaps look into some mathematical test to see if a given rotation quaternion rotates a vector (your up vector) onto a plane?

Comment: @Jake But why is it using the direction of the north for the gyroscope? Maybe it's combined with the magnetometer for some reason but a tried all quaternions and all euler angle equivalents and nothing seemed to work like I need it to, as every option was affected by rotating relative to the poles.